# how to get value of weka cluster centroid

Tags: java, weka, k-means

I am using weka kmeans classifier and i have build it a model.Now i want to cluster center value of each centroid.
I get it on weka UI

```
Attribute    Full Data          0          1
               (48836)    (39469)     (9367)
============================================
tt            428.6238   514.1345    68.3143
```

How can i get it using weka java jar?

My weka cluster training set has only one attribute.

To get attribute name i do:
String attname =clusterCenters.get(0).attribute(0).name();

How to get value of cluster center?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call to the method `getClusterCentroids()` in `SimpleKMeans` you get an `Instances` object (in weka-3-6-8). This is a set of instances that represent your cluster centers (one for each specified cluster).

```
SimpleKMeans kmeans = ...
// your code
...
Instances instances = kmeans.getClusterCentroids();
```

Once we have the set of instances (centroids), we can guess its size by `numInstances()`, iterate through them using `instance(int index)` and getting their values with `double value(int attIndex)` this way:

```
for ( int i = 0; i < instances.numInstances(); i++ ) {
    // for each cluster center
    Instance inst = instances.instance( i );
    // as you mentioned, you only had 1 attribute
    // but you can iterate through the different attributes
    double value = inst.value( 0 );
    System.out.println( "Value for centroid " + i + ": " + value );
}
```

And that is all.
I have not compiled the code, but that is the way I do it.

Comment: Is there any way to find the centroid index?

Comment: In above code i variable is the index of the instance that represent the centroid.